# Bitbucket new webhook not working

Tags: bitbucket, integration, webhooks

Bitbucket has improves its *Webhooks* functionality. We won't be able to create POST or Pull Request POST in *Services*, instead in *Webhooks*.

So I have tried to create POST request to Slack using new *Webhook*, but it doesn't work. Clicked on `View requests`, I got 500 error on the request. While with the same URL, it works in *Services*.

I don' know what I did wrong. Bitbucket documentation doesn't help. Can someone please help me?

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem, but I don't think this is a good StackOverflow question. Seems more like a question for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Graham is talking about [this](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/06/24/the-new-bitbucket-webhooks/) here. You maybe need to change your IP-whitelist to connect to your server. 
`131.103.20.160/27` `165.254.145.0/26` `104.192.143.0/24`.

I never used Posthooks. I m myself struggeling with the webhook [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128021/bitbucket-webhooks).

Comment: Your answers makes a lot of sense! I didn't notice that note on the webhook site. I will make it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same problem, and it appears to be a known issue with the integration (from the perspective of Slack).

As documented on slack.com:

> This integration only supports the **Repository push** trigger at this
>   time, so make sure it is selected. Press **Save** when you're done.

I'm not sure where to find a public link to this document, but you can find it if you go to add the bitbucket integration. And the documentation on slack appears to be up to date with the new bitbucket webhooks.

Hopefully one of the parties fixes it soon.

**Update:**
The integration appears to have started working in the last couple of days. At least for us with PR create/update/comment?approve/merge.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this documentation on slack.com?  I'd like to follow the issue if there is one.  Push notice is nice, but a bit lacking.

Comment: @theshawn In the last day or two, the integration appeared to just start working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to your issue, but I'm putting it here as it might help others, there's currently an open issue related to non-standard ports that has similar symptoms:

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/11514/webhook-fails-when-using-an-alternative

Answer (score -2):

Do you have any IP limits on what IPs can post to that end target? The new web hooks may be using different IP addresses than the old services.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you please give me some more hint?