# Bitbucket Webhooks

Tags: automation, bitbucket, git, scripting

I want to automate the deployment of one of my projects onto my server. 
I m using git via bitbucket to version control my software.
I came accross this [this](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/) nice tutorial. Unfortunately i cannot get it to work.

If i push changes from my local working copy, the remote repo gets updated but the webhook gives me the `404` error. So communication with my server was established but the script was not found.

When i manually start the script via `php bitbucket-hook.php` a pull request is issued on the repo and everything works as expected.

I guess  something is wrong with the URL. I tried `http://ip.ip.ip.ip/home/<username>/app/deploy/bitbucket-hook.php` and also the domain name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented the webhook myself quite a times.

The path you are using to access the .php file is incorrect. This path should be relative to your DocumentRoot of apache (eg /var/www/html)

say your DocumentRoot is /var/www/html then put your bitbucket-hook.php file in in this path (i.e. /var/www/html/bitbucket-hook.php) and use the URL as http://ip.ip.ip.ip/bitbucket-hook.php

Alternatively, you can make a Virtual host which points to / (root) and use http://ip.ip.ip.ip/home/{username}/app/deploy/bitbucket-hook.php

NOTE : you also need to add your .ssh folder with private key in /var/www as when you trigger the webhook then apache will find the key in its home folder i.e. /var/www.

Here is part of my bash which I have written to autodeploy

`

```
echo "implenting the web hook for auto deployment..."
if ! [[ -d /var/www/.ssh ]]; then
sudo cp -R ~/.ssh /var/www/
if [[ \$? == 0 ]];then
echo -e 'copied ~/.ssh to document root to apache [/var/www]\n'
else
echo -e 'something went wrong while copying ~/.ssh to /var/www\n'
fi
else
echo "Already a folder name .ssh in /var/www"
fi
sudo chown -R apache. /var/www/.ssh 2>&1
if [[ \$? == 0 ]];then
echo -e 'ownership of /var/www/.ssh has changed to apache \n'
else
echo -e 'something went wrong while changing ownership of /var/www/.ssh\n'
fi
pushd /var/www/html
touch auto_pull.php
sudo chown apache. auto_pull.php
echo -e "<?php content to write in php file ?>">>auto_pull.php  
popd
```

`

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Ecellent:) Works perfect.. thanks a lot! I also did not know about this path setting